# how to have all elements below a line with a proc-sql

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I try to got all elements with a condition in sql.

I give you an example, it will be very clear

Imagine I got it :

```
ID   date        type1    type2      money
 1   02/05/2021   R       U           500
 1   02/05/2021   R       R           400
 1   03/05/2021   Q       U           2500
 1   05/05/2021   Q       R           2900
 2   07/05/2021   Q       R           7900
 2   09/05/2021   Z       R           7900
```

Then I want got it :

```
 1   03/05/2021   Q       U           2500
 1   05/05/2021   Q       R           2900
 2   07/05/2021   Q       R           7900
 2   09/05/2021   Z       R           7900
```

I want to have only last elements below type1="R" and type2="R"

So when type1="R" and type2="R"  I try to have all elements below it ( like in my example)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you want to order your data? Without ordering "below it" is not defined.

Comment: I order it per ID

Comment: In your example all ID-s are 1. How can you order it?